# Implement Github Authentication and Authorization in a CLI App

Tags: node.js, github-api

I am creating a new CLI project where I want to use the Github API to create new repo's. When googling, I found out that Github has deprecated Authorization API in favour of Web Authorization flow. I can see that maybe we should use a local redirect URL in the CLI app but I don't understand how to get started with this. Basically I need to authorize users (preferably with the Web Flow) use their API from my CLI.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want people to enter their email + passwords in your CLI app? I think the simplest way is based on tokens.

Comment: I would prefer that a browser window opens once to authorize them. This way, I won't have to deal with passwords, but if there's no way, then I think people will have to manually add a token to work. I don't want my users to do that manual work.

Comment: GitHub has created a guide which explains in detail how to do this: https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/

Comment: You can try to use chrome in debug mode (and headless) and then open it in the background, fill the password and username for the user on the authorization page - and then check what it responds with to save the user tokens.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use authorization code flow with a Proof Key for Code Exchange. There is a really good article that I found [here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/18/command-line-app-with-nodejs#add-support-for-secure-authorization-with-pkce)